# $x$ x $1/x$ for $\epsilon$ $\gt 0$ has no $\epsilon$-neighborhood in $R_{+}$ x $R_{+}$

Tags: general-topology

This is a problem from Munkres' Topology.

Define the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ in a metric space $X$ to be the set 
$U(A, \epsilon) = ${$x$ | $d(x,A)$ $\lt$ $\epsilon$}.

(d) Assume that $A$ is compact and let $U$ be an open set containing $A$. Then some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ is contained in $U$.

(e) Show the result in (d) need not hold if $A$ is closed but not compact.

I have proved (d) and for (e), I am trying to show that $x$ x $1/x$ for any $\epsilon$ $\gt 0$ has no $\epsilon$-neighborhood in $R_{+}$ x $R_{+}$. This is intuitively clear but I am struggling to prove this rigorously. How can I show this?

Comment: what is $x$ x $1/x$ supposed to denote?

Comment: The graph {(x,1/x) | x$\in$ $R_{+}$}

Comment: I edited my answer to make it work with the graph of 1/x .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let $A$ be the graph of $1/x$, for, say, all $x>0$, and let $U$ be the upper open half-plane. Given any $\varepsilon>0$ take $x>\frac1\varepsilon$, that is $\frac1x<\varepsilon$. Then the point $(x,0)$ belongs to the ball with radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $(x,\frac1x)$, but does not belong to $U$. Clearly this ball is contained in the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $A$, but is not contained in $U$. In particular the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ is not contained in $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it has an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose any $x>\frac1\varepsilon$ to get a contradiction.